# i use angular-responsive-carousel library . But I can not change arrow design and dots design

Tags: css, typescript, sass, carousel, angular10

I use:: ng deep of css  style. I can change browser CSS. but it is not solved in my CSS code in angular 10.
here is my  code:

```
>  ::ngdeep .carousel-arrow {
>       background-color: lightblue;
>       background-position: 50%;
>       background-repeat: no-repeat;
>       background-size: 31px;
>       border-radius: 100px;
>       box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
>       cursor: pointer;
>       height: 40px;
>       margin-top: -20px;
>       position: absolute;
>       top: 50%;
>       width: 40px;
>       z-index: 10;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get through Angular's [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) in order to create a custom theme for the carousel component.
The best way to do this is by globally include a scss file.
You could create a theme e.g. `carousel.theme.scss` then you could import that via
`@import '<path/to/file>/carousel.theme.scss';` in you root `styles.scss`

In order to really get throgh the Angular view encapsulation it could additionally be necessary to use `!important` to reach your desired result.

`:host::ng-deep` (that would be the correct syntax) is considered deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: First, change ngdeep by ng-deep. Then, add !important to each style

```
::ng-deep .carousel-arrow {
         background-color: red !important;
}
```

instead of

```
::ngdeep .carousel-arrow
```

This way it works just fine.

[image]